# MacOS: Custom NSView won't show subviews

Tags: swift, macos, subview, addsubview

I have a View Controller and added a Subview to its View. The class of the Subview should also have some Subviews etc. Here is my code of my custom Class:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class PercentageShower: NSView {

    let percentageBar = NSView()

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor.black

        let testsubview = NSView(frame: frameRect)
        testsubview.wantsLayer = true
        testsubview.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor.init(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.addSubview(testsubview)
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }
}
```

This is the ViewControllers code:

```
class Basics1ViewController: NSViewController {

let percentageShower = PercentageShower()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set screen mesurements:
        let screen = NSScreen.main
        let screenWidth = (screen?.frame.width)!
        let screenHeight = (screen?.frame.height)!

        // Set Percentage View
        percentageShower.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
        self.view.addSubview(percentageShower)

   }
}
```

This is just an example, but why isn't my red colored subview shown? I can see the black colored view itself but not it's subview. Looking forward to your help!

Comment: Try changing your conde from init(frame:) to did move to superview method

Comment: Did you try "view debugging"?